# why using one-hot encoding rather than askii or unicode?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

askii or unicode alse can recognized in computer.
But why using one-hot encoding?
One-hot encoding also doesn't show similarity between words, than what is better?
Specifically what information is in one-hot encoding?

Comment: You want to watch you english and focus your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.